# Exporting using django-import-export and showing verbose names of related objects

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11, django-import-export

I was having a look at the following library - django-import-export.
However, I am having issues with exporting with friendly/verbose column names for related objects.

Related link: https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/52

```
class HumanModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
def get_export_headers(self):
    headers = []
    for field in self.get_fields():
        model_fields = self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields()
        header = next((x.verbose_name for x in model_fields if x.name == field.column_name), field.column_name)
        headers.append(header)
    return headers

class Meta:
    model = Human
    fields = ("name", "pet__name")

class HumanAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = HumanModelResource
    list_display = ("name", "pet")

class Human(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Name")
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet)

class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Pet Name")
```

Exporting will show "Name" for the human but the pet name will show up as "pet__name".

I'm not sure how to approach overriding the get_export_headers method to display the related objects verbose name.

I am currently using:
- Python 2.7
- Django 1.11

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your `get_export_headers()` is failing because the `x.name == field.column_name` match fails (`x.name` = `pet` and `field.column_name` = `pet__name`).

So, you could fix that particular bug, but there's another way that's more in line with Django Import/Export's API: explicitly define the foreign key relationship.

```
from import-export import resources, fields

class HumanModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

   petname = fields.Field(
       attribute="pet",
       column_name="Pet Name",
       widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Pet, "name")
   )

   class Meta:
       model = Human
       fields = ("name", "petname") # note the change
```

(Note: Untested.)

Comment: Works for me without the need for the widget. thanks